# Problem with a static method: "cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, android, function, android-activity, static

I have this method that I have in every activity (which just works) but can I make a 1 activity like API and call this function from any activity? and would this be a good solution? Instead of having the same function in every activity?

I have this function in a clean activity and want to call this function from any activity. 
In these lines I get the error: **cannot be referenced from a static context**

```
final String email = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail();
final TextView bottom_bar_points = findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar_points);
...
MySingleton.getmInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

I would love to see some advice, thanks in advance.

### Code

```
    public static void getMyPoints() {
        final String email = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail();
        final TextView bottom_bar_points = findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar_points);
        String uRl = "https://mywebsite.com/getmypoints.php";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.equals("Found")) {
                    bottom_bar_points.setText(response);
                    return;
                } else {
                    bottom_bar_points.setText(response);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                bottom_bar_points.setError(error.toString());
                return;
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("email", email);
                return param;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MySingleton.getmInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete this and ad a Context variable with parameters:

```
public static void getMyPoints(Context contex) {
.....
}
```

So you replace this by context. Your code will be :

```
public static void getMyPoints(Context context) {

final String email = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).getUserEmail();
final TextView bottom_bar_points = **findViewById**(R.id.bottom_bar_points);
String uRl = "https://mywebsite.com/getmypoints.php";
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if (response.equals("Found")) {
            bottom_bar_points.setText(response);
            return;
        } else {
            bottom_bar_points.setText(response);
            return;
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        bottom_bar_points.setError(error.toString());
        return;
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("email", email);
        return param;
    }
};
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
MySingleton.getmInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

}

in your activity call this method with:

Activity.getMyPoints(getBaseContext())

Answer (score 0):

you can use from interface  like below:
it is better to seperate your app data logic and view best is use inteface..
do it is testable and clean

```
public class GetFromServer{
        private OnGetDataListener listener;
        public getData(){
          String uRl = "https://mywebsite.com/getmypoints.php";
          StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, new 
          Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                listener.onGetData(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 listener.onGetData(error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
         DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
     }
     public void setOnGetDataListener(OnGetDataListner listner){
       this.listener=listener;
     }
     public interface OnGetDataListner{
       void onGetData();
    }
  }
```

in All activity that you neeed do this:

```
 public Activty extends AppCompactActivty implements{

      public onCreate(){
        new GetFromServer().setOnGetDataListener(this);
      }
      public void onGetData(String response){
        //here you can use from response
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 parameters to the function:

```
Activity A {

    public static void getMyPoints(Context context, View view) {

       ...

    }

}
```

and change your lines in which you get the error as I do below:

```
final String email = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).getUserEmail();
final TextView bottom_bar_points = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar_points);
...
MySingleton.getmInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

---

You can call this method in this way:

```
Activity B {

   A.getMyPoints(getApplicationContext(), getCurrentFocus());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I will explain the reason. according to the class loader mechanism. the static variable and method which is load when compile. but the instantiation object, in the current situation; it is `this`. it is created when the program runs. so you can not directly use it.

Secondly, there have some solutions. one you can do pass it by a method params. but you should take care of the memory leak. if your SharedPrefManager is a single object. I don't suggest to use this way. you should use the `ApplicationContext`.  if not it is no problem.

if wan to use it you can replace the context(this) use the application context.

```
public static void getMyPoints(Context context)
```

besides it, you can also create a base activity, then others Activity extends it. the method can use in every subclass activity.

```
class BaseActivity {
  public void getMyPoints(){ 
    ....
  }
}

class SubActivity extend BaseActivty{

   public void doSomething(){
       getMyPoints();
   }

}
```